# No such module 'CropViewController'

Tags: swift, carthage

macOS Sierra 10.12.2
Xcode 8.2.1
Swift 3.0.2

- Create a new project Create Cartfile and write github
  "sprint84/PhotoCropEditor" ~> 1.2
- carthage update --platform iOS
- Open
  project In ViewController.swift, write import CropViewController
- Follow instructions of Carthage

  - Add PhotoCropEditor.framework in
    Linked Frameworks and Libraries
  - Add script in Build Phases
  - Add the
    path of PhotoCropEditor.framework

With above case, import CropViewController fails because of No such module 'CropViewController' .

I tried to create a new project again, then I could install and build Alamofire with Carthage.

Does this library require any additional instructions?
Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: [README of this library](https://github.com/sprint84/PhotoCropEditor/blob/master/README.md#usage) says to import individual class.

Comment: Anyway, I wrote `import PhotoCropEditor`, then `module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.2` was displayed

Comment: Ah, it fixed! update Carthage with typing `carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries` then `import PhotoCropEditor` solved the error!